# Most efficient way to store data that changes infrequently in Xarmin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I am new to app development and I am doing a proof of concept app in  Visual Studio 2017 community. The aim is to have Android and IOS versions.

The app purpose is to record five exercises results per test and give a pass / fail result based on a set of targets per exercise. The test targets will depend on the age, gender, and level of the person completing the test

For example a test target for a male 25 year old level 1 maybe

1. Push ups Target 22
2. Shuttle runs in 60 seconds Target 20
   And so on

I expect to have two hundred  lines of targets for all the variation of users, age, gender and levels. In particular, if i consiser sqlite (which i am using in the project already to store student info and results) I am thinking of how to seed the initial data table. If I code by a static resource file on first start I can read the  data file (xml / csv /json) and seed the data table of targets and replace that file later to re-import  using an app setting to signify  a re-seed of the data table is required, but I am  concerned I am "bloating" the App size and wondering what format is more efficient to read in

These targets will not change very often but may be review once a year and changed

In WPF I would create an  a csv or Json file with this data in as a resource and read it in a plain C# class to model the targets. However on reading up there is concern about such static files "bloating" the size of the finished app and delays in creating the list of targets when in use and that there is no native csv library

I would also like to be able to import new data (targets) into the resource file

What is the most efficient way to achieve this please

Comment: Create an API REST service where the app can pull the data when is needed

Comment: I am writing this for a small karate association  so do not have access to a website for API. I am considering it from point of view chief instructor has an excel sheet of these targets and they could produce (xml or csv?) a file of the updated targets and publish to the Facebook group for the students to download and the update the app. Also there may not be wifi coverage at classes when the test are done so not API

Comment: If your data does not content sensitive information you can put it on a jSON file and pull it from a dropbox shared link

Comment: Yes ok. is there a Dropbox library for xarmin? And examples of how to achieve this as like I say abit new to this :-)

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-download-files-in-xamarin-forms/ I think that you don't need an special library since it will be a shared link that doesn't need authentication

Comment: I will check it out thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your scenario correctly you need to save 5 targts for each user then [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences) might be worth considering. It uses shared preferences on Android and NSUserDefaults on iOS.

If you have more information to save, then SQLite seems like a good option.

Comment: Hi you are correct in your understanding. I shall take a look. but I expect to have two hundred  lines of targets for all the variation of users, age, gender and levels. In particular, if i consiser sqlite (which i am using in the prohect already to store studebt info and reaults) I am thinking of how to seed the initial data table. If I code by a static resource file on first start I can read the  data file (xml / csv /json) and seed the data and replace that file later to re-import  using an app setting to signify  a re-seed of the data table is required, but concerned if I am "bloating" the

Answer (score 1):

Review option to put "initial" DB file as a resource. So, you can prepare as DB structure as seed data. At first startup, app will be in need to just copy to document directory and use it (simple binary copying of the resource as is).

Later time, you will need some kind of code snippet that will merge changed data from new "initial DB file" to your local one at document directory.

Comment: Ok that makes sense in concept but uncertain of how to achieve what would the search phrase to find any good examples to work from